# Как удалить элемент многомерного массива?

Tags: php

Нужно удалить дубликат. Не хочет удаляться никак: ни с помощью unlink, ни так, как здесь.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Goods) - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($Goods); $j++) {
        if ($Goods[$i]['Cost'] === $Goods[j]['Cost']) {
            $Goods[$i] = NULL;            
        } else {
            $j++;            
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Вячеслав Потапов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

`else{$j++;}` из кода уберите.
И советую `count($Goods)` сохранить в переменную, чтобы постоянно функцию не вызывать.